# How to compare elements in an array list using the index provided by another arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList: A` containing `array` of indexes something like this `[[0,1],[4,5,6]]`. This list is dynamic and may grow in size based on some prior operations that I do
I have 2 more integer `arraylists` of equal sizes say `7`. something like this:
`B: [1,1,4,5,2,3,2]` and `C: [3,3,4,5,6,6,6]`

I need help to compare the elements at indexes represented by `arrayList: A` in `B` and `C` seperately

*Example:*

compare elements in arrayList B at index `[0,1]` and check if `list.get[0] == list.get[1]` and for `[4,5,6]` check if  `list.get[4] == list.get[5] == list.get[6]`

same for `array list C`

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: please share what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Just as you would say it, use the values of arraylist `A` as indexes for the other lists:

Example **A = [0,1] , B[3, 3]**

You need to check if:

```
B[0] == B[1]
```

but rewriting the indexes as values of `A` you get:

```
B[A[0]] == B[A[1]]
```

Just extend this to the general case and you have solved the problem.

Comment: make sure to do proper bounds checking too

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean checkIndex ( List<List<Integer>> indexList, List<Integer> listToCheck ){
    for (List<Integer> indices : indexList) {
        int val = listToCheck.get( indices.get(0) );
        for (int i = 1; i < indices.size(); i++) {
            int index = indices.get(i);
            if ( listToCheck.get(index) != val ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would loop all index list and check for all values of the corresponding index in the other list.

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
    indexList.add(Arrays.asList(0,1));
    indexList.add(Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
    System.out.println(indexList);
    List<Integer> tempList = Arrays.asList(1,1,4,5,2,3,2);
    List<Integer> tempList2 = Arrays.asList(3,3,4,5,6,6,6);
    System.out.println(tempList);
    System.out.println(checkIndex( indexList, tempList));
    System.out.println(tempList2);
    System.out.println(checkIndex( indexList, tempList2));
}
```

//Output

```
[[0, 1], [4, 5, 6]]
[1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2]
false
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
true
```